# Texto de descripción en búsqueda de pagina desde Google

Tags: wordpress, seo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto donde dice

> Cambiar navegacion. Enercosta. Ir al contenido etc...

Quiero se se cambie por la descripcion de mi pagina.

Estoy utilizando wordpress y el plugin YoastSeo.

Comment: Ese plugin te pone la metaetiqueta description o siempre la has tenido? Hace cuánto tienes andando YoastSeo?

Comment: La metaetiqueta description ya la estoy utilizando que es el texto de la imagen "Energias renovables de la costa"

Comment: Ok, si ví que la tienes, pero mi pregunta era si la tenías desde antes de usar YoastSeo. Y la pregunta de fondo en realidad es hace cuánto tiempo está esa metaetiqueta ahí, con o sin plugin. Pregunto esto porque google actualiza los datos de búsqueda con una demora que puede ir desde pocas horas hasta varias semanas.

Comment: La estoy utilizando desde hace mucho tiempo y el plugin YoastSeo tambien, Apxoimadamente Dos Meses

Comment: Bueno, dos meses cae en el rango de "varias semanas". Yo no veo que estés haciendo nada mal, sino que google te indexó antes de que tuvieras la descripción actual.

Comment: Mira este [artículo de la documentación de Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=es) sobre cómo pedir que se reindexe tu sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Con el plugin Yoast Seo no te haría falta añadir una metadescripción en el código, como te ha dicho Jose puedes editar la descripción de la pagina principal y las nuevas entradas individualmente o puedes crear una metadescripcion por defecto para todas las paginas en el menu de opciones del plugin. Esto también tardaría en tener efecto en google, por lo que tendrías que esperar para ver el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ir en el panel de control, después editar la pagina principal y en la parte de abajo te aparecerán las opciones del Plugin Yoast SEO. Hay que cambiarlo donde dice "Editar snippet".